# Dimensions of an uploaded image

Tags: jquery, image, dom

I need to get the dimensions of a user uploaded image that is, there is a file upload button that loads the image into an 'img' tag and then depending on the size of the img, the img element attributes are set. Essentially, upon page load, the image tag is much like this:

```
<img id="img">
```

when the user uploads an image of dimensions  222 X 227, the dimensions rendered to it are:

```
<img id="img" width="222" height="227"> <!--verified by inspecting the element -->
```

I want to retrieve the dimensions of the uploaded image and am using jQuery, my script:

```
$('#img').attr('width') OR $('#img').attr('height');
```

return 'undefined'. also, `$('#img').attr('src')` returns `undefined` even though upon inspecting the element does in fact show these attributes to be loaded with the correct values.

This makes me conclude that the image was uploaded but not added to the `DOM` perhaps?

Anybody know what's up ?

Comment: need to see more code, sounds like you are looking for element before it exists

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out what's up, doing this helped:

```
$('#img').load(function(){
   console.log($('#img').attr('width'));
});
```

gives me the dimension that i want. However, I have no idea why I needed to do the load() function callback here, if anybody wants to shed light on it.

Comment: On `DOM` ready - the document markup, code, and the images path are read, but not yet loaded, that's why you need a `.load`